# How can I avoid using the stack with continuation-passing style?

Tags: clojure, lisp, scheme, state-machine, continuations

For my diploma thesis I chose to implement the task of the [ICFP 2004 contest](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~plclub/cgi-bin/contest/ants.html).

The task--as I translated it to myself--is to write a compiler which translates a high-level ant-language into a low-level ant-assembly. In my case this means using a DSL written in Clojure (a Lisp dialect) as the high-level ant-language to produce ant-assembly.

**UPDATE:**

The ant-assembly has several restrictions: there are no assembly-instructions for calling functions (that is, I can't write `CALL function1, param1`), nor returning from functions, nor pushing return addresses onto a stack. Also, there is no stack at all (for passing parameters), nor any heap, or any kind of memory. The only thing I have is a GOTO/JUMP instruction.

Actually, the ant-assembly is for to describe the transitions of a state machine (=the ants' "brain"). For "function calls" (=state transitions) all I have is a JUMP/GOTO.

While not having anything like a stack, heap or a proper CALL instruction, I still would like to be able to call functions in the ant-assembly (by JUMPing to certain labels). 
At several places I read that transforming my Clojure DSL function calls into continuation-passing style (CPS) I can avoid using the stack[1], and I can translate my ant-assembly function calls into plain JUMPs (or GOTOs). Which is exactly what I need, because in the ant-assembly I have no stack at all, only a GOTO instruction.

My problem is that after an ant-assembly function has finished, I have no way to tell the interpreter (which interprets the ant-assembly instructions) where to continue. Maybe an example helps:

The high-level Clojure DSL:

```
(defn search-for-food [cont]
  (sense-food-here? ; a conditional w/ 2 branches
    (pickup-food ; true branch, food was found
      (go-home ; ***
        (drop-food
          (search-for-food cont))))
    (move ; false branch, continue searching
      (search-for-food cont))))

(defn run-away-from-enemy [cont]
  (sense-enemy-here? ; a conditional w/ 2 branches
    (go-home ; ***
      (call-help-from-others cont))
    (search-for-food cont)))

(defn go-home [cont]
  (turn-backwards
    ; don't bother that this "while" is not in CPS now
    (while (not (sense-home-here?))
      (move))) 
    (cont))
```

The ant-assembly I'd like to produce from the `go-home` function is:

```
FUNCTION-GO-HOME:
  turn left nextline
  turn left nextline
  turn left nextline ; now we turned backwards
SENSE-HOME:
  sense here home WE-ARE-AT-HOME CONTINUE-MOVING
CONTINUE-MOVING:
  move SENSE-HOME
WE-ARE-AT-HOME:
  JUMP ???

FUNCTION-DROP-FOOD:
  ...

FUNCTION-CALL-HELP-FROM-OTHERS:
  ...
```

The syntax for the ant-asm instructions above:

```
turn direction which-line-to-jump
sense direction what jump-if-true jump-if-false
move which-line-to-jump
```

My problem is that I fail to find out what to write to the last line in the assembly (`JUMP ???`). Because--as you can see in the example--`go-home` can be invoked with two different continuations:

```
(go-home
  (drop-food))
```

and

```
(go-home
  (call-help-from-others))
```

After `go-home` has finished I'd like to call either `drop-food` or `call-help-from-others`. In assembly: after I arrived at home (=the `WE-ARE-AT-HOME` label) I'd like to jump either to the label `FUNCTION-DROP-FOOD` or to the `FUNCTION-CALL-HELP-FROM-OTHERS`.

How could I do that without a stack, without PUSHing the address of the next instruction (=`FUNCTION-DROP-FOOD` / `FUNCTION-CALL-HELP-FROM-OTHERS`) to the stack? My problem is that I don't understand how continuation-passing style (=no stack, only a GOTO/JUMP) could help me solving this problem.

(I can try to explain this again if the things above are incomprehensible.)

And huge thanks in advance for your help!

--
[1] "interpreting it requires no control stack or other unbounded temporary storage". Steele: Rabbit: a compiler for Scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ant assembly language is not even Turing-complete. You said it has no memory, so how are you supposed to allocate the environments for your function calls? You can at most get it to accept regular languages and simulate finite automata: anything more complex requires memory.  To be Turing-complete you'll need what amounts to a garbage-collected heap.  To do everything you need to do to evaluate CPS terms you'll also need an indirect GOTO primitive.  Function calls in CPS are basically (possibly indirect) GOTOs that provide parameter passing, and the parameters you pass require memory.

Comment: After actually looking at the contest (briefly), it looks to me like it *is* turing-complete, but only if the world is arbitrarily large. Specifically, you can consider the world to be the "tape"; you have an ability to alter the world and (if I read correctly) to read those marks. Still, leveraging this to try to solve the problem is probably absurd, as you point out.

Comment: I should also add: the number of states allowed is pretty big, so you could model a certain set of programs by representing the state as one of these state numbers, and just arrange to explode and give up if the compiled program tries to, say, represent a number that's too big.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you've provided the precise motivation for continuation-passing style.

It looks like you've partially translated your code into continuation-passing-style, but not completely.

I would advise you to take a look at [PLAI](http://www.plai.org/), but I can show you a bit of how your function would be transformed, assuming I can guess at clojure syntax, and mix in scheme's lambda.

```
(defn search-for-food [cont]
  (sense-food-here? ; a conditional w/ 2 branches
   (search-for-food
    (lambda (r)
      (drop-food r 
                 (lambda (s)
                   (go-home s cont)))))
   (search-for-food
    (lambda (r)
      (move r cont)))))
```

I'm a bit confused by the fact that you're searching for food whether or not you sense food here, and I find myself suspicious that either this is weird half-translated code, or just doesn't mean exactly what you think it means.

Hope this helps!

And really: go take a look at [PLAI](http://www.plai.org/). The CPS transform is covered in good detail there, though there's a bunch of stuff for you to read first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! Yes, the weird code is only a half-translated example. But my real concern right now is not how to transform my code into CPS, but whether CPS is a solution for my original problem (i.e. simulating function calls without a stack, without passing parameters and only with one GOTO) or not. But I'll definitely look into PLAI!

Comment: Wait... how about two out of three?  A program in CPS requires no stack, and all function calls can be made using a GOTO mechanism.  The procedures definitely still take parameters. If you want to get rid of these, you can safely use global registers (since function calls don't have to resume after calls to other functions).

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, your two basic options are to inline everything, with no "external" procedures (for extra credit look up the original meaning of "internal" and "external" here), or somehow "remember" where you need to go on "return" from a procedure "call" (where the return point does not necessarily need to fall in the physical locations immediately following the "calling" point).  Basically, the return point identifier can be a code address, an index into a branch table, or even a character symbol -- it just needs to identify the return target *relative to the called procedure*.

The most obvious here would be to track, in your compiler, all of the return targets for a given call target, then, at the end of the called procedure, build a branch table (or branch ladder) to select from one of the several possible return targets.  (In most cases there are only a handful of possible return targets, though for commonly used procedures there could be hundreds or thousands.)  Then, at the call point, the caller needs to load a parameter with the index of its return point *relative to the called procedure*.

Obviously, if the callee in turn calls another procedure, the first return point identifier must be preserved somehow.

Continuation passing is, after all, just a more generalized form of a return address.

Comment: Yes, inlining is truly an option. (Though not a final solution, because the specification of the task limits the size of the source code.)

Your "remembering"-solution sounds good, but now the problem is that I explained the specification incompletely (sorry!). The ant-assembly is for to describe the transitions of a state machine (=the ants' "brain"). There are no variables (though they can be simulated by duplicating the code), no memory (stack or heap), and most importantly no specific CALL instruction. So I can't write `CALL function1, param1`.

Comment: Therefore I can't "load a parameter with the index of a return point" as you suggested. Or maybe I can, only I don't know how to do that within these limitations (and exactly that's what I'm trying to figure out).

For "function calls" (=state transitions) all I have is a JUMP/GOTO. Which--according to the CPS literature--seemed to be enough. But I'm slowly arriving to the conclusion that something else is needed too.

Comment: OK, how about this: grouping states in a state machine equals functions in a higher-level language. I'd like to enter to one group-of-states from different locations (=I'd like to call one function from different call sites), and I'd like to continue execution towards different group-of-states (=after the function finishes, I'd like to call different continuations/functions).

Comment: Yep, a parameter is "state" -- just different terminology.  You can have a state for each possible return point, in effect.  I did virtually the same once in a microprogrammed processor design, where the program memory was purely associative with no program counter.  (For my design I implemented "come from" (the associative memory), which basically associated a given target instruction with a state pattern that would cause it to be executed.  Then it would set a new state.)

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in Andrew Appel's book *Compiling with Continuations*.

Comment: Thanks! I skimmed through it and didn't immediately find an answer to my question, but that only means that I have to read it again more carefully.